# If with two conditions based on two cells

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, offset, multiple-conditions

I need to add a second condition to my code.

If Len = 3 and UPC is blank, then move the Group Code left 1 column.
I've the action part resolved. The second condition has me stumped.

I tried `And` in the same line with the two conditions.

I tried what you see below.

The Group codes are in Column C.
The UPCs are column E.
If cells in C, len = 3 AND UPC in same row, column E = "" (blank) then proceed otherwise skip.

I added:

```vb
Dim UPC As Range
Set UPC = Range("E2:E" & LastRow)
If UPC.Value = "" Then
```

Here is the code:

```vb
'Moving Group Codes
Dim cell As Range
Dim UPC As Range
Set UPC = Range("E2:E" & LastRow)
For Each cell In Intersect(Range("C:C"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
    If Len(cell.Value) = 3 Then
        If UPC.Value = "" Then  '<<<<<<this is where i get my error.
            cell.Cut Destination:=cell.Offset(columnoffset:=-1)
        End If
    End If
Next cell
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a question here? If you have a compound condition which needs to be satisfied that can be expressed as "if x and y then do something..." or as "if x then if y then do something..." With both of these constructs, both x and y must be true in order to proceed to do something. (Tip: The reference to yesterday's problem is not very helpful. If that adds context to the question, I'm completely clueless because I haven't seen the referenced question. Perhaps this inquiry should be moved to "yesterday's question, or perhaps you should comprehensively restate the question here.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet, cell As Range
Dim UPC As Range

Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set UPC = ws.Range("E2:E" & LastRow)
For Each cell In Intersect(ws.Range("C:C"), ws.UsedRange).Cells
    If Len(cell.Value) = 3 Then
        If Len(cell.EntireRow.Columns("E").Value) = 0 Then  '<< check ColE value on same row
            cell.Cut Destination:=cell.Offset(columnoffset:=-1)
        End If
    End If
Next cell
```